# Keeping unique observations by specific column in data table

Tags: r, data.table

Suppose I got a data table with multiple columns. I want to update this data table in such a way that only unique observations by a pre specified column appear. For example,

```
data.table(c(1,2,2,3,4),c(2,3,5,4,3))
```

should be transformed to

```
data.table(c(1,2,3,4),c(2,3,4,3))
```

Here the pre-specified column is the first one
I tried to use unique() function, but it returns vector with unique values  and does nothing with the data table itself

Comment: Maybe something like: `dt1[, list(V2 = min(V2)), by = V1]`

Comment: `dt[!duplicated(V1)]`